# RadioButton Get ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: selectedRadioButton must not be null )

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

So I Implement a simple How RadioGroup And RadioButton Work In Kotlin Programming language And I use the `setOnClickListener`  method to make my apps can click like another app, and I use Fragment to Implement my simple RadioGroup And RadioButton apps.

when I pass the SetOnclick for this method :

```
 submitButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                val selectedId = surveyRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
                val selectedRadioButton = rootView.findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId)
                Log.d("TEST", selectedRadioButton.text.toString())

                dismiss()
            }
```

I Got an Error.

this is full of my code in above of that code :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class MyFragment : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false)
        val cancelButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancelButton)
        var submitButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitButton)
        var surveyRadioGroup = rootView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.myradiogroup)


        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                dismiss()
            }
        })

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                val selectedId = surveyRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId
                val selectedRadioButton = rootView.findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId)
                Log.d("TEST", selectedRadioButton.text.toString())

                dismiss()
            }

        })
        return rootView
    }
}
```

this is my dialog_fragment.xml for connecting XML class and Kotlin class Above code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/myradiogroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Exellent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Very GOOD"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Good"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:text="Average"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Bad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>
        
        <Button
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            />



        <Button
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this app has created a requirement for Androidx

Answer (score 0):

`selectedRadioButton` is null because:

```
val selectedRadioButton = rootView.findViewById<RadioButton>(selectedId)
```

is called inside `onCreateView()` i.e. `rootView` hasn't been created at this point.

Set your views in `onViewCreated()` instead.

Comment: can you please give the full of code about onViewCreated() instead.

Comment: The idea of stackoverflow is to answer questions not to provide code that you can just copy and paste.

Comment: You can look at the android developer docs if you want information about onViewCreated(). It's important you learn about these lifecycle methods.

Comment: okay thank you for reminding me about the copy-paste, I so appreciate you.

Comment: If this solves your problem please vote for this answer.